# How do you create a new dictionary from a list, using positions to dictate keys and values?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am trying to determine the most used active users in certain packages. I have a list with the packages and users as the elements. I would like to turn these into dictionary with the package name as the key and the username as the value. The pattern of the list is :

```
list = ['package1', 'userA', 'userB', 'package2', 'userC', 
        'userD', 'package3', 'userE', 'userF', ...]
```

I would like:

```
dict = {'package1': ['userA', 'userB'], 
        'package2': ['userC', 'userD'],
        'package3': ['userE', 'userF'],
        ...}
```

I would like to be able to match the package by name and not by position. I currently have something like:

```
dict={}
for x in list:
    if "package" in x:
        dict.fromkeys(list, x)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How can you tell the difference between "packages" and "users"?  Are there always exactly two users mentioned after each package?

Comment: At most there are two users but as little as one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach using a simple iteration.

**Ex:**

```
lst = ['package1', 'userA', 'userB', 'package2', 'userC', 'userD', 'package3', 'userE', 'userF']
result = []
for i in lst:
    if i.startswith("package"):
        result.append([i])
    else:
        result[-1].append(i)

result = {i: v for i, *v in result}
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'package1': ['userA', 'userB'],
 'package2': ['userC', 'userD'],
 'package3': ['userE', 'userF']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code;

```
In [1]: raw_data = ['package1', 'userA', 'userB', 'package2', 'userC', 'userD', 
   ...: 'package3', 'userE', 'userF']                                           

In [2]: data = {}                                                               

In [3]: for el in raw_data: 
   ...:     if el.startswith('package'): 
   ...:         lastkey = el 
   ...:         data[el] = [] 
   ...:     else:
   ...:         data[lastkey].append(el) 
   ...:                                                                         

In [4]: data                                                                    
Out[4]: 
{'package1': ['userA', 'userB'],
 'package2': ['userC', 'userD'],
 'package3': ['userE', 'userF']}
```

Comment: This appends the package names to the lists, which isn't part of the questioner's desired output. If you fix that (by putting `data[lastkey.append(el)` in an `else` block) you'll end up with almost the same code I suggest in my answer (though you're caching the package name, while I'm caching the associated list value).

Answer (score -1):

If you can rely upon there always being exactly two users, then you ca easily use a dictionary comprehension with indexing and slicing to produce the keys and value-lists that you need:

```
output = {lst[i]: lst[i+1:i+3] for i in range(0, len(lst), 3)}
```

If the number of users might be variable though, you'll need a full loop. You need to remember the most recent package you've seen, and put each subsequent user into its associated list:

```
output = {}
current_package = unpackaged_users = []
for item in lst:
    if item.startswith('package'):
        current_package = []
        output[item] = current_package
    else: # or elif item.startswith('user')?
        current_package.append(item)
```

The `unpackaged_users` variable will contain a list of any users that were included in the input before the first package was seen. If that can't happen in your code, you could probably do away with that variable (and if you don't initialize `current_package` before the loop, you'll get an exception if that situation ever comes up).